# DataTable Format

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatable, date-format

I have a question. I'm working on asp.net c#, and I would like to change the date format of a DataTable. The DataTable gest the source from SQL, and is performed as `dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss`, I would like to change into `dd/mm/yyyy`. If I execute the query in SQL, I get the format as I wish, the problem is in the DataTable. Also, I set datatable to a ReportViwer. Thanks.

EDIT: this my code to give datatable a format

```
DataTable table=(get the source from SQL);
for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    string date= "";
    Calendar cl = new Calendar();
    date= table.Rows[i]["LimitDate"]= .ToString();
    cl.SelectedDate = System.DateTime.Parse(date);
    table.Rows[i]["LimitDate"]= cl.SelectedDate.Day.ToString()
     + "/" + cl.SelectedDate.Month.ToString()
     + "/" + cl.SelectedDate.Year.ToString();
}
```

If I run the code below for a GridView, it works. However, for a DataTable it is not working

Comment: How do you output the data to the user?  Surely there's somewhere to include a format string to customize the `DateTime` value?

Comment: You should show the code used to retrieve the data into the data table, as well as describe the column types.

Comment: I had added the code so you can see it

Comment: if you are using a dynamic sql, a view or a stored proc to get your datatable you might format the date directly into the sql, so you avoid to assign the datatable another time only to format your date..

Comment: Thakns, Ciro Corvino. It worked as you suggested :D

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't compile. And anyways, it looks like you are storing dates as strings in the database. You should use the appropriate data type for your database, such as `datetime` for SQL Server. You should only format the date to a string when you are ready to present it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `table.Rows[i]["LimitDate"]=cl.SelectedDate.Day.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");`

or take a substring of dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss format string